# Memory sharing issue between arrays

Tags: python, arrays, memory, multiprocessing

I'm sharing 3 arrays between several processes and it's working perfectly. However, when creating a 4th or 5th one, it seems their memory slot get overridden by each other

e.g. 
    I have something like this:

```
a = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, 5000)
b = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, 5000)
c = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, 5000)
d = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, 5000)
e = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, 5000)
f = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, 5000)
```

I then create the processes that fill these arrays (they are independent processes that update differnt parts in the arrays)

```
for i in range(0,10):
    process = mp.Process(target=myFunction, args=(a, b, c, d, e, f))
    process.daemon = True
    process.start()
    processes.append(process)

for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

Once the processes are done, I can see that a and b and c are correctly filled. However, d, e and f don't have any of the values assinged in "myFunction". They 
have instead the same values that c has.

It looks like to me that there is a kind of limit when reserving the memory slots for the arrays c, d, e and f and they share actually the same space.

Is this possible?

Comment: We would need to see `myFunction`.

Comment: ...or some simplified version of `myFunction` that exhibits the same problem.

Comment: myFunction (a,b,c,d,e,f)
  for i in range 5000
   a[i] = value1
   b[i] = value2
   c[i] = value3
   d[i] = value4
   e[i] = value5
   f[i] = value6

Comment: in this case "i" is different for every process so they are updating the array in different sections.

Comment: I've been analyzing it a bit more and I've just found out that it seems the problem is here when I do the resizing.

Comment: This provides the expected results:        print(a[0])
        print(b[0])
        print(c[0])
        print(d[0])
        print(e[0])
        print(f[0])